# Angular 1.4.8 causing ngOptions with "group by" to double results in IE 11

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

I'm noticing something weird in Angular 1.4.8

I have a select box that has the following `ngOptions` value:

```
test.value as test.label group by test.group for test in model
```

Because I have the `group by` clause, all of the options are doubled.  There are some other weirdnesses with adding and removing values from `model` and having them not disappear from the select box as well.

I built a quick example to show what I mean

Angular 1.4.8: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGzRmy
Angular 1.4.7: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGzRJL

Is this something I'm doing incorrectly or is this a bug in Angular?

### EDIT

I just checked 1.5.0 RC 0, and it also doubles the options list

### EDIT 2

Tested on IE 11.  Because of Enterprise Group Policy, that is the only browser allowed at my work. Here is a screenshot of what's happening

[image]

Comment: They are both the same to me

Comment: I don't see any differences between 1.4.7 and 1.4.8. Tested on Chrome 47

Comment: What browser? Works fine for me in chrome and firefox on windows

Comment: IE 11, just updated with a picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running into the same problem with IE10 and IE11.  This appears to have been fixed with the 1.5.0 RC1 release.